# how can i generate apk of my app which include library project?

Tags: android, apk, library-project

I want to generate the apk file of my app which have a reference of the library project.I am using eclipse.It gives error like "Android library project cannot be exported".
How can i generate apk.Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have included the library project for licensing purpose

Comment: Its done now. I have some unexpected in project.properties file. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this may be helpful to you.
    Right click on your application -> select android tools -> Export signed application package -> and select browser and sign certified keystore select and give pw
    create sign certificaiton keystore  using http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to exoprt the library project, use the application project that references the library.

Comment: same case with me.My app have a reference to the library project. But i m not able to generate the apk file

Answer (score 0):

For those on Eclipse, I just opened the project.properties and replaced FROM THIS:

```
#project target
android.library=true
```

TO THIS

```
android.library=false
```

Then I compiled as usual, either by export menu or right clicking the project > Android Tools > Export Signed Aplication Package.